# Remove "Detach" right click from Eclipse RCP MPartStack

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

Is there a way to remove "Detach" right click from context menu in MPartStack?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just tell e4 that the part is not detachable by add the tag

```
NoDetach
```

to the part (or part descriptor) Tags in the Application.e4xmi.
[image: Tags with NoDetach]

Or you can completely replace the tab menu using a custom stack renderer. You override the `populateTabMenu` method:

```
public class MyStackRenderer extends StackRenderer
{
  @Override
  protected void populateTabMenu(Menu menu, MPart part)
  {
     // TODO your menu items
  }
}
```

You set up your renderer using a renderer factory:

```
public class MyRendererFactory extends WorkbenchRendererFactory
{
  private MyStackRenderer myStackRenderer;

  @Override
  public AbstractPartRenderer getRenderer(MUIElement uiElement, Object parent)
  {
    if (uiElement instanceof MPartStack) {
       if (myStackRenderer == null) {
          myStackRenderer = MyStackRenderer();
          initRenderer(myStackRenderer);
       }

       return myStackRenderer; 
    }

    return super.getRenderer(uiElement, parent);
  }
}
```

You tell Eclipse about the renderer factory using the `rendererFactoryUri` in the product definition.

```xml
<extension
      id="product"
      point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
   <product
         .... 

      <property
            name="rendererFactoryUri"
            value="bundleclass://xxxxx.MyRendererFactory">
      </property>
```

Comment: NoDetach is on the individual Parts in the part stack, not the part stack. The stack renderer calculates the menu using the current part. I tested NoDetach here and it definitely works.